# Firefox transitions not working

Tags: css, firefox, transition

This is my CSS setup:

```
#element1, #element2{
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
  -o-transition: left 0.3s;
  transition: left 0.3s; 
}

body.open #element1, body.open #element2 {
   left: 245px; 
 }
```

The problem is that the transition just doesn't work in Firefox, it's fine in all other browsers.

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: The HTML isn't really anything special, I just have those 2 divs that i want to animate.

Comment: animate on hover? Can you post a complete example on jsfiddle?

Comment: here's a basic fiddle, again it works in chrome, but not in FF:
http://jsfiddle.net/sK7Wk/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a starting left for firefox (and now Chrome).

```
#element1, #element2{
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: left 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: left 0.3s;
    -o-transition: left 0.3s;
    transition: left 0.3s; 
}
```

You're going to be better off always setting a default value for any transition. That way you can have complete control.

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome need initial left value for transition left to work.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli care to share what did work for you? Just tried the fiddle in Chrome and Firefox and it worked without issue.

Comment: #div1, #div2 {
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
Works very well on Chrome but simply does not work in Firefox.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running? It honestly works for me, and has for quite some time. It's even nicer than it use to be. Before you had to transition from like units (px->px) and so using a unit-less 0 was an issue. You're essentially saying that transitions do not work in Firefox, which I know is not the case.