# Firefox translation left doesn't work

Tags: css, firefox, transition

I'm trying to get this http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB07061TJ template to animate sidebar under Firefox (other browsers works fine). I figure out so far that firefox needs `left` to be set explicitly [Firefox transitions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844198/firefox-transitions-not-working)

I tired to add left to all possible combination and elements but still no slide animation.

Comment: where is your tried code ??

Comment: Well the code is just left: 0px added to sidebar and sidebar class