# jquery UI add class with animation does't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

See my jsfiddle (apologies for putting the javascript into the html body but somehow it did not work placing it in the javascript field):

http://jsfiddle.net/40mga4vy/

I want to change css classes of the #wallpaper div by selecting it from a select field (far right side).

So I first remove the current css class and then add a css class based on the value from the select item.

```
function changeBackground() {
    $('#wallpaper').removeClass();

    $("#wallpaper").addClass("wallpaper_" + $("#select_category").val(), 1000, "easeOutBounce");

};
```

I am following the jquery UI documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/addclass/
because I want to have an animation when the new class gets added.

However, there is no animation!
I tried various jquery and jquery UI versions but nothing changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define transition rule in CSS. Then background image will change with animation effect:

```css
#wallpaper {
    /* ... */
    transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/40mga4vy/2/

Comment: great. how's browser compatibility here?

Comment: + any idea why my fiddle e.g. the addclass method didn't work?

Comment: Good answer but to add to it, You will need prefixes. `-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;` and lastly you can chain the JQuery methods by doing `$('#wallpaper').removeClass().addClass(...);`

Comment: @DeanMartin No prefixes needed these days. Only maybe -webkit if Andriod support is needed.

Comment: @DonMB I still don't know why your code is not working. It is the same as the jquery page told. I tried a lot of things in the fiddle but nothing works. Are you sure you loaded Jquery and JqueryUI properly?

Comment: @dfsq Somehow it doesn't work on Firefox - looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844198/firefox-transitions-not-working but no success

Comment: Yes @Vinc199789 - 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

I have now an animation on image change. I first let the Jquery change the image, then set the opacity to 0 and than with the jquery `animate()` I animate the opacity to 1.

I this is you new script:

```
 function changeBackground() {
    $('#wallpaper').removeClass();

    $("#wallpaper").addClass("wallpaper_" +      $("#select_category").val()).css('opacity','0').animate({opacity:'1'});
 };
```

Take a look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40mga4vy/1/)